# HACKRF_ERROR_NOT_FOUND

Tags: software-defined-radio, hackrf

I have connected my HackRF to my computer that runs Ubuntu and it was working fine until now. It gives me an error:

```
FATAL:Failed to open HackRF device(-5) HACKRF_ERROR_NOT_FOUND
```

Has anyone had the same experience?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to involve USB permissions under Ubuntu, so perhaps your question would have been better-suited for [askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/).  But you probably didn't know that when you asked, so we shouldn't really hold that one against you ;)

Anyway, your question seems to be the first one in the [HackRF FAQ](https://github.com/mossmann/hackrf/wiki/FAQ).  If the advice there were short I would repeat it here, but it isn't, so I won't.  Good luck, I hope their advice helps you solve your problem!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the HackRF as root to determine if it works. Also try adding yourself to the `dialer` group in `/etc/group` - that works for me with my SDR dongle. What's the `dmesg` output when you plug it in?